# Extend Search API: Create and expose custom sort/filter from db_table

Tags: 7, views, search

I have a geocoded field for each node of a certain type. It simply geocoded the address filled in the node create form.

I've multiple views based on the search api (database not solr) and use facets on these views to filter them.
I do not want to change anythiong about the facets, I just want to sort the view by distance based on the geolocation values I already have for them.

How do I extend the search_api module and expose my db_table to it (after modifying the values to work out the distance relative to starting point).

For some strange reason search api does not even allow sorting with the most basic of fields, such as node title =/

see: http://drupal.org/node/1422942